# Cucumber reporting and browser hiding

Tags: ruby, cucumber, hudson, watir, bdd

I'm using cucumber (ruby) + watir for running behavior driven tests, and I'm trying to do a couple of things for integrating it with Hudson CI:

- Currently, the browser window pops up on the build slave each time the job runs. Is there a way to hide the browser window while the tests run?
- I am using the jUnit formatter and having Hudson parse the test results. However, I'd like to print a test summary with the feature/scenario names and the test result (pass/fail) on the console window so that the email notification sent out lists the test summary. How do I do that?
- Currently, cucumber prints a lot of debug output including deprecated function warnings. The `-q` flag doesn't seem to do anything for me. Is there a way I can stop cucumber from printing anything on the screen?

Edit: I'm running the tests on a Windows 7 desktop.

Comment: If you're on linux, you can run watir in [headless](http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/) mode.  Another option might be phantomjs.

Comment: @orde I updated my question - I am running this on a windows 7 build slave. Do you have any resources on watir + phantomjs?

Comment: Check out @JustinKo's blog post: https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2014/07/26/specifying-the-path-for-the-phantomjs-executable-2/